# How can I determine if a dynamic array has not be dimensioned in VBScript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

Say I create a dynamic array in VBScript

```
Dim myArray()
```

Later on how can I check to see that this array has never been dimensioned?

```
Ubound(myArray) 'sub script out of range
Lbound(myArray) 'sub script out of range
IsEmpty(myArray) 'returns false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built in, but you can create your own function as:

```
Function IsInitialized(a)    
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    UBound(a)
    If (Err.Number = 0) Then 
        IsInitialized = True
    End If
End Function
```

Which you can then call as:

```
Dim myArray()
If Not IsInitialized(myarray) Then
    WScript.Echo "Uninitialized"
End If
```

However, one way to work around it might be to not declare empty arrays, instead declare just a variable and set it to an array later, so change the code above to:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array()
If Not IsInitialized(myarray) Then
    WScript.Echo "Uninitialized"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to `Not` the Array, and then compare the result to `-1`. This works, and does so without intentionally causing an error.

```
Dim myArray()

...

If (Not myArray) = -1 Then
    ReDim myArray(0)
Else
    ReDim Preserve(0 To UBound(myArray)+1)
End If
```

Comment: Wonderful little hack.

Comment: @Lankymart, how did you declare the array?

Comment: Tried both dynamic and fixed `Dim myArray()` and `Dim myArray(0, 0)`, also tried `ReDim`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using something like this:

```
Dim arr
arr = null

sub addElement (byref arr, element)
    if isNull (arr) then
        redim arr(0)
    else
        redim preserve arr (uBound(arr) + 1)
    end if
    arr(uBound(arr)) = element
end sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Came across this while looking for an answer to the same question, I initialized a variable to 0 and increment it only when I add to the area and then just check for the variable value instead...

dim myarray()
num=-1
if addtoarray then
num=num+1
redim preserve myarray(num)
end if
if num>-1 then
 do something
end if